# Having trouble P/invoking UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect() from C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke, user32

Currently my application makes use of the [UpdateLayeredWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx) function in user32.dll and it works very well, but I am trying to replace it with a call to [UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633557(v=vs.85).aspx) to take advantage of the `prcDirty` flag in the [UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632609(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.

At the moment, the [UpdateLayeredWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx) P/invoke is done as follows:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool UpdateLayeredWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcDst, ref Point pptDst,
        ref Size psize, IntPtr hdcSrc, ref Point pprSrc, int crKey,
        ref BLENDFUNCTION pblend, BlendFlags dwFlags);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BLENDFUNCTION {
    public byte BlendOp;
    public byte BlendFlags;
    public byte SourceConstantAlpha;
    public byte AlphaFormat;
}

public enum BlendFlags : uint {
    None = 0x00,
    ULW_COLORKEY = 0x01,
    ULW_ALPHA = 0x02,
    ULW_OPAQUE = 0x04
}

//UpdateLayeredWindow() called here
public UpdateMethodHere() {
    UpdateLayeredWindow(handle, hdcWindow, ref dest, ref size, hDC, ref src, 0, ref blend,
        BlendFlags.ULW_ALPHA);
}
```

The variable types match the delegate, and the function call works as intended.

Then I tried replacing the call with [UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633557(v=vs.85).aspx) as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect(IntPtr hwnd,
    ref UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO updateInfo);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO {
    public static readonly int Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO));
    public int cbSize;
    public IntPtr hdcDst;
    public POINT pptDst;
    public SIZE psize;
    public IntPtr hdcSrc;
    public POINT pptSrc;
    public int crKey;
    //BLENDFUNCTION is the same as in the first part of the question
    public BLENDFUNCTION pblend;
    //BlendFlags is the same as in the first part of the question
    public BlendFlags dwFlags;
    public RECT prcDirty;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT {
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y) {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SIZE {
    public long cx;
    public long cy;

    public SIZE(long width, long height) {
        cx = width;
        cy = height;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT {
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;

    public RECT(int left, int top, int width, int height) {
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        right = left + width;
        bottom = top + height;
    }
}

//UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect() called here
public UpdateMethodHere() {
    UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO info = new UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO() {
        //the variables on the right-hand size used here are the same as the
        //ones used in part 1 of the question
        cbSize = UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO.Size,
        hdcDst = hdcWindow,
        pptDst = new POINT(dest.X, dest.Y),
        psize = new SIZE(size.Width, size.Height),
        hdcSrc = hDC,
        pptSrc = new POINT(src.X, src.Y),
        crKey = 0,
        pblend = blend,
        dwFlags = BlendFlags.ULW_ALPHA,
        prcDirty = new RECT(src.X, src.Y, size.Width, size.Height)
    };
    UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect(handle, ref info);
    Console.WriteLine(new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
}
```

On the console I am getting the message: `The parameter is incorrect`. I have tried changing the SIZE struct variables to be of type `int` instead of `long`, but then I get an `Invalid access to memory location` message in the console.

Is anyone able to spot what is incorrect about my delegate and/or struct signatures that pertain to the [UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633557(v=vs.85).aspx) P/invoke?

Comment: `*pptDst` and similar are the issue. Because it's a pointer, you should use an array with a single entry, e.g. `public POINT[] pptSrc`

Comment: Probably also want `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=1)]`

Comment: Let me try and I'll get back to you.

Comment: When computing the size `(cbSize)` using `Marshal.SizeOf()`, I am getting an ArgumentException: `UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.` How do I work around this?

Comment: It is going to be a painful slog.  The pptDst, pSize, pptSrc, pblend and prcDirty fields are pointers but you declared them as a value.  They'll have to be IntPtr.  With a lot of code to generate the pointers from Marshal.StructureToPtr().  A little C++/CLI can do wonders here.

Comment: I'll try using Marshal.StructureToPtr() first.

Comment: Using Marshal.StructureToPtr() worked! Thanks @HansPassant, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Although it worked, UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect() has a greater performance overhead than UpdateLayeredWindow() (ie. prcDirty is useless).